# Using nsIFilePicker.modeGetFolder within addon sdk

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

My addon creates a `Panel`, which shows currently selected preferences for the addon.
I'd like to populate the `Panel` with a `button`, who's `onclick()` event creates a dialog allowing user to specify which directory to save files in.
This was possible with the XUL based addons but the same code does not work within an sdk based addon as `window` is not accessible.
Any ways around this?
Within the addon code, I create the `Panel` using:

```
var confirmDialog = require("sdk/panel").Panel({
    width: 250,
    height: 250,
    contentURL: data.url("confirmDialog.html"),
});

confirmDialog.port.on("selectDir", function () {
    chromeManager.selectDir();
});
```

`confirmDialog.html` specifies the `Panel`'s content:

```
<div id="pathToFile"></div>
<button onclick="Panel.selectDir();">
</button>
```

`confirmDialog.js` sends message to addon code:

```
var Panel = {

    selectDir: function() {
        addon.port.emit("selectDir", '');
    }
};
```

`chromeManager.js` is part of the addon code, so it has access to the sdk API.

```
exports.selectDir = function() {

    var nsIFilePicker = Ci.nsIFilePicker, 
    fp = Cc["@mozilla.org/filepicker;1"].createInstance(Ci.nsIFilePicker);

    fp.init(window, nsIFilePicker.modeGetFolder);

    var ret = fp.show();

    if (ret == nsIFilePicker.returnOK || ret == nsIFilePicker.returnReplace) {
        document.getElementById('pathToFile').value = fp.file.path;
    }
}
```

However I get `ReferenceError: window is not defined` when running this code, is there any way to make `window` accessible here or an alternative way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use [`window/utils`](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/modules/sdk/window/utils.html), in particular `getMostRecentBrowserWindow()`, to obtain a reference to the active window for use with the `nsIFilePicker` API.

Comment: `fp.init(require("sdk/window/utils").getMostRecentBrowserWindow(), "Select", nsIFilePicker.modeGetFolder)` did the trick, thanks